# Setting an active button after a POST operation using PHP and bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'd appreciate your help with this!

Here is my bootstrap HTML code:

```
        <div class="form-group centered">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="login" value="Log In"></input>
        </div>

        <div class="centered">
          <div class="form-group btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-default active">
              <input type="radio" id="app" value="app" name="dashboard"/>Application
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
              <input type="radio" id="setup" value="setup" name="dashboard"/>Setup
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I would like to add some logic that after the "Log In" button is selected, the "active" class on the label is retained properly.

Example:

1. Setup is selected
2. The user clicks login
3. The password is wrong so the user is thrown back to the same log in form
4. This time the form has the setup button "active" automatically

I tried playing around with the following within the app input type:

```
<?php if($_POST['dashboard'] == "app") { echo checked="\"checked\""; } ?>
```

I now realize, however, that this button group does not work like a regular radio button, and I probably need to toggle the class on the labels somehow.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working piggybacking on the advice of user1844933 :)

```
        <div class="form-group centered">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="login" value="Log In"></input>
        </div>

        <div class="centered">
          <div class="form-group btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-default <?php setAppDefault( $lastDashboardSetting ); ?>">
            <input type="radio" value="app" name="dashboard"/>Application
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default <?php setSetupDefault( $lastDashboardSetting ); ?>">
              <input type="radio" value="setup" name="dashboard"/>Setup
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
```

My PHP code:

```
$lastDashboardSetting = $_POST['dashboard'];

function setAppDefault( $setting ) {
    if( $setting === "app" ) 
        echo "active";
    else
        echo "";
}

function setSetupDefault( $setting ) {
    if( $setting === "setup" ) 
        echo "active";
    else
        echo "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

php

```
 if($_POST['dashboard'] == "app" { $appchk='checked'; } else {$appchk='';}

 if($_POST['dashboard'] == "setup" { $setupchk='checked'; } else {$setupchk='';}
```

HTML

```
<input type="radio" id="app" value="app" name="dashboard" <?php echo($appchk);?>/>Application

<input type="radio" id="setup" value="setup" name="dashboard" <?php echo($setupchk);?> />Setup
```

Comment: And I did close the php if statement above.  Thanks for trying to help me!  I've been bashing my head against the wall to get this working.  If I switch to simple radio buttons I know how to get this working...